# Javascript Date.parse() works unexpected

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, date

I'm trying to compare dates from a JSON to a `var = Date.Now();`
Dates from JSON look like this: `2015-09-28T15:36:00`
The Date.now variable like this: `Mon Sep 28 2015 17:35:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)`

I want to know if the time at this moment is between two JSON dates.
So i tried to convert them to milliseconds with `Date.parse()` but now it seems there is a time difference of 2 hours. I could simply say "add 2 hours" but i would like to know a better solution, and to know what i'm doing wrong.

So this is the console:

```
MeetingStart    = a :   2015-09-28T12:30:00
MeetingStop     = b :   2015-09-28T15:36:00
Clock           = c :   Mon Sep 28 2015 17:35:59 GMT+0200 (CEST)
$scope.a = :   1443443400000
$scope.b = :   1443454560000
$scope.c = :   1443454559000
```

And this the code:

```
$scope.kijkOfMeetingBezigIs = function(meetingStart,meetingStop){

    $log.info("MeetingStart     = a :   "+meetingStart)
    $log.info("MeetingStop  = b :   "+meetingStop)
    $log.info("Clock            = c :   "+$scope.clock)
    $scope.a= Date.parse(meetingStart);
    $scope.b= Date.parse(meetingStop);
    $scope.c= Date.parse($scope.clock);
    $log.info("$scope.a = :   "+ $scope.a)
    $log.info("$scope.b = :   "+ $scope.b)
    $log.info("$scope.c = :   "+ $scope.c)

    if ($scope.a < $scope.c && $scope.b > $scope.c ) {
        $log.info("meeting is gestart..");
        $scope.ruimteVrij = false;
        $scope.ruimteBeschikbaarheidText = "Ruimte bezet";
    }else{
        $log.info("meeting is gestopt..");
        $scope.ruimteVrij = true;
        $scope.ruimteBeschikbaarheidText = "Ruimte vrij";
    }

};
```

THANKS! ;)

Comment: There's really no such thing as a "JSON date". Something  is giving you those strings, and they look like ISO-format dates, but that's just one possible way of encoding a date.

Comment: Also: JavaScript runtimes that parse ISO dates without explicit time zone information assume you want them parsed as UTC timestamps. Thus I'm guessing you're two hours away from GMT. (*edit* - oh, durr; I guess I didn't have to guess :)

Comment: :) i ment to say: dates i get through a JSON-file not JSON dates ;)

Comment: So is there a way to parse them with explicit time zone information? The only way i found where libraries like  http://momentjs.com/timezone/ but this looks a bit much for just editing the timezone...

Comment: Well if you're *getting* the dates in that format, it'd be a little weird to "fix" them. It might be better if you'd make sure to always work with UTC, which the [JavaScript Date API makes possible.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)